# display number of text columns depending on number choosen in a choice column

Tags: javascript

I want to create a jscript to display number of columns depending on number of columns choosen. e.g if i choose 1, it should display column 1(text) and if i choose 2 it should display two text columns and so?

Answer (score 0):

I have prepared a sample code based on my understanding of your requirement ,It may help you

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#trid1").hide();
$("#trid2").hide();
var noofField=2;
$("#text").focusout(function(){

    if($.isNumeric( this.value ) )
    {

        for(i=1;i<=this.value;i++)
        {
            $("#trid"+i).show();
        }
        if(this.value<noofField)
        {
            var j=noofField-this.value;
            for(k=0;k<=j;k++)
            {
            var l=parseInt(this.value)+j;
            $("#trid"+l).hide();
            }
        }
    }


});

});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</p>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="text" value="" id="text">
 </tr>

<tr id="trid1">


<td>
<input type="text" value="1">

</td>
</tr>


<tr id="trid2">

<td>
<input type="text" value="2">
</td>

</tr>

</body>
</html>
```

in the above code based on value entered in the first input field ( id=text) the other two field are shown